# Shutting down system using task scheduler feature

Tags: windows-xp, schtasks

I am working on a network with multiple systems with windows XP. My aim to schedule a system shutdown at a specific time, but i don,t want everybody to set it manually. Just a click on the .cmd file i will be sending them shall do the needful.

For this i tried to prepare a .bat file with following command

shutdown -s -f -t 0 -c "Go Green"

Now i want to include this in the task scheduler, with the following command:
SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC weekly /D MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /TN Kill /ST 11:04:00 /TR "C:\Users...."

The task is not running at all.
Please help with your suggestions.

Comment: are you certain that the file to execute "C:\Users.." exists on every computer?

Answer (score 1):

Your users need the "shutdown privilege" local and remote, and the file "C:\Users.." must exists on each computer.
There is an answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305591/win-xp-remote-shutdown-from-user-account) about this and on an other [q&a site](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/shutdown-exe-doesnt-run-due-lack-privileges-t179004.html), both explain how to set the privileges in gpedit.